# Google Play Language Setting

Tags: applications, google-play-store, settings, languages

I am currently using Samsung Galaxy S2. Recently I found that there are a lot of different language application in the Google play store. I can understand both English and Chinese but It seem like I am getting application of different languages. For example, in the bottom list in google play lifestyle top new free app, it show me application of languages that i don't even know how to read it.

Is there a language setting where i can display app that shows only English?

[image: Different Languages in Google Play Lifestyle Top New Free APP]